# Why does Drax think Rocket Raccoon could kill him?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

When Gamora takes Peter, who just got saved by Rocket Raccoon, with her, Drax says this words to Rocket Raccoon:

> What are you doing? **You could've killed us all**!

This happens exactly at 1h:32min:44sec

Comment: Can you give us a bit more context?

Comment: I would imagine that the answer is quite plain, however few people watch a movie with stopwatch in hand. So providing context by explaining the preceding actions would most likely answer the question for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe I know the scene you're talking about. Peter's being drained by Ego, and Yondu and Rocket crash their ship into Ego's building. The rest of the Guardians break in, distracting Ego, then Yondu crashes his Ravager pod ship into Ego and crushes him.

That's the part that Drax was talking about. Note the rest of his conversation is something like:

> DRAX: What are you doing? You could have killed us!
>
> ROCKET: Uh, thank you would be nice!
>
> DRAX: We had it under control!

When Yondu crashes the ship into the building, he had no way to know who would be there to be crushed. Has Drax been standing in the wrong spot, *he* would have died when the ship slammed into them. He also thinks that he, Gamora, and Nebula would have been able to fend off Ego by themselves.

So, in Drax's mind, Yondu and Rocket didn't save them, he actually risked killing them by recklessly smashing into a building full of people.